# How to get an index array for same value in a vector?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm a beginner in C++ and meet a problem.

Assuming there is a vector of integers, how could we get the index array for the same value?

i.e. If the vector is: [a,a,b,c,a,c,b,c] where a, b, c are integers.

Then the expected index arrays should be:

v_a = [1,2,5], v_b = [3,7], v_c = [4,6,8]

Is there any simple way in C++ to implement this?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: This is a basic iterative algorithm that you can easily do on your own.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thanks for reply. I tried something: By comparing the elements in vector with the value of first elements, we get the index array of the first value. But I have no idea about how to check the location of second value.

Comment: This is no tutorial site or a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it is better to use `std::multimap` in this case because the number of different integers in the original array is unknown and as I understand can be changed.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main( void )
{
    std::vector<char> v = { 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c' };
    std::multimap<char, size_t> m;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ) m.insert( { v[i], i } );

    for ( auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); )
    {
        auto p = m.equal_range( it->first );

        while ( p.first != p.second )
        {            
            std::cout << p.first++->second << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

        it = p.second;
    }        
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 4 
2 6 
3 5 7
```

Take into account that array indices start from 0 in C++.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And I wonder does it mean that to use the solution above we need to convert the vector from integers into characters?

Comment: @XhivaW  It is enough to substitute char for int. I used char because you used symbols a, b, c and so on.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer and your kindness. I will try to understand this and see if I could run it locally. @Vlad from Moscow

Comment: Sorry for bothering. But it seems the definition of "it" and "p" isn't compatible with c++98 cause when I compile this without "-std=c++11", there occur "error: ‘it’ does not name a type" and  " error: ‘it’ was not declared in this scope". Is there any way to define in c++98? @Vlad

Comment: @XhivaW In C++ 98 you have to declare it explicitly like for example std::multimap<char, size_t>::iterator it. The same should be done with the declaration of p.

Comment: Many thanks! There are lots of thing I need to learn in C++ : ) @Vlad

Comment: I did what you told but it doesn't work and  there occurs two extra error: ‘std::multimap<int, long unsigned int>::iterator’ has no member named ‘first’ and ‘std::multimap<int, long unsigned int>::iterator’ has no member named ‘second’ @Vlad

Comment: @XhivaW  I think that these error messages refer to the declaration of p. p must be declared like std::pair<std::multimap<int, long unsigned int>::iterator, std::multimap<int, long unsigned int>::iterator> p...

Comment: I tried but seems it doesn't work... Maybe I should run the program in C++11 to avoid this. Thanks again! @Vlad

Comment: @XhivaW  It should work. What error does the compiler issue?

Comment: I declare it and p as: "std::multimap<int, size_t> it; std::pair<std::multimap<int, long unsigned int>::iterator, std::multimap<int, long unsigned int>::iterator> p;" and when I compile this only by "g++ codefile.cpp", it shows 3 errors. 1st: error: ‘it’ does not name a type. 2nd: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘it’. 3rd:   error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘std::multimap<int, long unsigned int>’ and ‘std::multimap<int, long unsigned int>::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, long unsigned int> >}’). And the last one with a very long explanation.... @Vlad

Comment: @XhivaW Include header utility and you should use either std::multimal<int, size_t> or std::multimap<int, unsigned long> in the both iterator declarations. In general it is not necessary that size_t is an alias for unsigned long.

Comment: Include <utility> and change <int, unsigned long> to <int, size_t>, but nothing changes : ( @Vlad

Comment: @XhivaW Show the first error message and the statement that is the reason for the error.

Comment: Here it is: index.cpp:17:16: error: ‘it’ does not name a type
     for ( auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); )
                ^
@Vlad

Comment: @XhivaW We already discussed that you have to replace auto with the  exact type did not we?

Comment: Sorry I missed it. So assuming the vector of integers, I need to change auto to int. Is that right? @Vlad

Comment: @XhivaW Please reread the comments. There was already discussed how the iterators should be declared.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to take in account that in C++ (as in C and Java and many others languages), array's and vector's indexes start at 0. N size means N - 1 positions. For example: one vector/array with 3 elements, goes from index 0 to index 2.

In your example: v_a = [0,1,4], v_b = [2,6], v_c = [3,5,7]

```
int a, b, c;
vector<int> integers;
vector<int> v_a;
vector<int> v_b;
vector<int> v_c;

void indexes(){
  for(int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++){

    if( integers[i] == a )
      v_a.push_back(i);
    else if( integers[i] == b )
      v_b.push_back(i);
    else if( integers[i] == c )
      v_c.push_back(i);
  }
}
```

Well this is the solution for your problem. Since you're learning C++, you may want to take this solution and try to make it more generic.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! But there is a point that I missed in my question. I don't know how many integers would appear in the vector. i.e. there may be only a, b and c, but probably there may be a, b, c and d. What  about this situation?

Comment: So you need to keep an additional vector that tracks if you already saw the int or not. I'll change the code, give me 2 min.

Comment: Well look at @Vlad from Moscow response. He nailed it faster than me.

Comment: Thanks all the same, for your answer and kindness! @Miguel Cunha